# Disallowing Juxtaposing Keywords

Tags: rascal

I tried implementing SQL's DDL syntax in rascal to get this result:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE page_view(viewTime INT, userid BIGINT,
     page_url STRING, referrer_url STRING,
     ip STRING COMMENT 'IP Address of the User',
     country STRING COMMENT 'country of origination')
 COMMENT 'This is the staging page view table'
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '<hdfs_location>';
```

but instead the code below is also valid:

```sql
CREATEEXTERNALTABLE page_view(viewTime INT, userid BIGINT,
     page_url STRING, referrer_url STRING,
     ip STRING COMMENT 'IP Address of the User',
     country STRING COMMENT 'country of origination')
 COMMENT 'This is the staging page view table'
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '<hdfs_location>';
```

is there a way to reject this syntax?

Below is the production rule:

```
syntax CreateTable
  = withColumns: 'CREATE' TemporaryTable? ExternalTable? 'TABLE' IfNotExists? TableName 
                        Columns?
                        Comment?
                        PartitionedByClause?
                        ClusteredByClause?
                        RowFormatClause?
                        StorageClause? 
                        LocationClause?
                        TablePropertiesClause?
  | withQuery: 'CREATE' TemporaryTable? ExternalTable? 'TABLE' IfNotExists? TableName 
                    RowFormatClause? 
                    StorageClause?
                    CreateTableQuery
  | withLike: 'CREATE' TemporaryTable? ExternalTable? 'TABLE' IfNotExists?  TableName Like TableName 
                    TablePropertiesClause?
  ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use + instead of * for the layout definition. That will make whitespace necessary everywhere. It becomes problematic with nullable nonterminals because then two spaces are required instead of one.
- Use follow requirements or precede requirements like `"SELECT" >> [\ \n]`
- Redefine the grammar:  `lexical CREATEEXT = "CREATE" " "+ "EXTERNAL"`
- Add a `" "` between the keywords in the original rule, but you have to play with the follow restrictions on layout to avoid a parser error.

So many options... you could also reject "CREATEEXTERNALTABLE" from the identifiers:

```
Id \ "CREATEEXTERNALTABLE"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like the only issue is that it would not cover all cases I will edit the question with the snippet of the production rule @jurgen

Comment: And also it would lead to a lot of repetition in the syntax rules @jurgen

Comment: You could introduce a nonterminal to share the constraint between all the places where you need it.

Comment: Thanks @jurgen, I would try that. According to the recommendation I would remove space from the `layout` and then specify it as a `lexical` nonterminal to be use anywhere in the code, right?

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. Are we mixing two stack overflow questions? I was saying that if you have a restriction that has to be reused, you can make a nonterminal that has it and use it were needed. Like `lexical NotFollowAZ = () !>> [A-Z];`